# ajax props/state not able to passed to class reactjs

Tags: ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Trying to pass state to child component is not working. I am using Reactjs ES6 to call ajax and on success, pass the first data id as an initial state for my child component. but inside same component, it works well.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid,Row,Col,Collapse,FormGroup,FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       UserFullName: this.props.UserFullName,
       token:this.props.token,
       UserCampList:[],
       SelectedCampId:'',
       filterText: '',
       filterBy: '',
     }
  }

  handleChange=(event,eventKey)=> {
       this.setState({SelectedCampId:event.target.value,filterText:event.target.value,filterBy:'advertiser'});
  }

  _getCamp(UserFullName,token){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:9000/csd/camp/user/Daniel%20Graham',
      //url: 'http://localhost:9000/csd/camps/user/'+UserFullName,
      contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success:(data)=>{
            if(data == ""){
              this.setState({ErrorMessage: "Camp data not available"});
            }else{
              this.setState({UserCampList:data,SelectedCampId:data[0].campId});
            }
        }, error:(e)=>{
          this.setState({ErrorMessage:e.statusText});
        }
    });


  }
  componentWillMount(){
    (this.state.UserFullName)?this._getCamp(this.state.UserFullName,this.state.token):"";
  }

  render(){
    return (
       <Grid className="content"> 
       <Row>
       <Col  xs={6} md={4}>  
        <div className="err">{this.state.ErrorMessage}</div>            
        <form>
          <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect"  ref="advertisersDD" className="adv-list" value={this.state.selectedAdvertiser} onChange= {this.handleChange} >
              <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="Adversiers">
              {
                this.state.UserCampList.map((Camp,i)=> {
                  return <option key={i} value={Camp.CampId}>{Camp.advertiser}</option>;
                })
              }
              </FormControl>
              </FormGroup>
        </form>
        </Col>
        <Col  xs={6} md={4} > 
            Search
        </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
        {this.state.SelectedCampId} ----
          <Table SelectedCampId={this.state.SelectedCampId}/>
          {this.state.SelectedCampId} ---000
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}


class Table extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    this.state={
       SelectedCampId:this.props.SelectedCampId
    };
  }
render(){
    return (
            <div>
               {this.state.SelectedCampId} Camp Id
            </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
15004354 ---- //before calling Table component
camp Id // Inside Table component
15004354 ---000 //after calling Table component
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` should probably not have its own state. If it does and the state depends on the props passed in, then you would need to update the state when you get new props. You can do this via [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops).

This is what happens right now in your code:

1. First render: `SelectedCampId` is `''`. `Table` is constructed and copies that value into its state and renders its state.
2. Second render (after Ajax call): `SelectedCampId` is `'123'`. `Table` is updated, it receives a new value as prop and ignores it.

Since there is nothing in `Table` that requires state, you should simply directly use the props:

```
class Table extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.SelectedCampId} Camp Id
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or as a stateless function:

```
function Table({SelectedCampId}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {SelectedCampId} Camp Id
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 worked. But...I have to make ajax call based on that value...like class Table extends React.Component{
  _getCampaign(){
    console.log(this.props.SelectedCampId+"table")
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this._getCampaign();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.SelectedCampId} Camp Id
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Comment: @tv3free: *"But...I have to make ajax call based on that value"* Where? What prevents you from doing an Ajax call? I don't understand what you are trying to tell me with the comment.

Comment: My code is in that comment. if I add _this.getCampaign function to the class and request for the props as console.log(this.props.SelectedCampId), I couldn't run _getCampaign in componentWillMount function.

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't be able to do that. Are you getting an error or why are you arriving at the conclusion that you cannot run that function? The lifecycle methods have nothing to do with props or state.

Comment: I am not getting the value inside the _getCampaign function. But I get the value when I render the html. `class Table extends React.Component{
  _getCampaign(){
    console.log(this.props.SelectedCampId+"table")
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    this._getCampaign();
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.SelectedCampId} Campaign Id
      </div>
    );
  }
}` I get "0table" & "12341 Campaign Id".

Comment: Well, when `componentWillReceiveProps` is called, `this.props` still refers to the old props. The new props are passed to `componentWillReceiveProps` as argument. Please read the documentation!

Comment: I tried with ComponentWillMount or ComponentDidMount, Nothing worked. Which should I use to enable the function?

Comment: All the lifecycle methods are called at different times. The *Mount methods for example are only called once when the component is mounted (similar to the constructor). `*WillReceiveProps` is called every time the component gets new props. What to choose depends on your needs. See the documentation to learn more about each of these methods. I can't help you since I don't know what you are trying to achieve with `_getCampaign`.